# Wi-Fi not appearing in Settings and icon not showing

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows and my Wi-Fi adapter is not working. In windows Wi-Fi works fine. If I use my Ethernet cable, the connection works fine. Using the Wi-Fi adapter, however, I don't even have the option or setting to connect. In Settings I don't see *Airplane Mode* too.

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 3 times, but still no Wi-Fi.

My system has an AMD Ryzen 5 5600H CPU, a NVIDIA Geforce RTX 3060 graphics card and an SSD. I also have UEFI BIOS and have disabled Secure Boot.

How can I make Wi-Fi work?

Comment: The CPU and graphics card models are not really relevant for this problem. Please [edit] your question and add the output of `lspci | grep WiFi` so we know your wireless adapter's model.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog `grep WiFi` is no good.

Comment: @Pilot6 You're right. A better command to find your wireless adapter's model is `lshw -C network`. So @Mihai [edit] your question and add the output of this command.